# Large time gaps between votes in the Review Reopen Queue

Tags: support, review

Questions in the Reopen queue don't last for more than a minute, so I'm curious, how is there such a large time span between the second-to-last vote and the last vote?

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1514370#./1514370?&_suid=136077430928106676949985798315
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1514046#./1514046?&_suid=1360771276359011990456602324828

In the first example, at the time I'm posting this, there is a 17 minute gap between votes, and in the second example, there is at least a 30 minute gap between votes.

Here's a real weird one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1474597#./1474597?&_suid=136077623335908487293546818277

The second-to-last vote was on Feb 7 at 13:39, and the last vote was yesterday?

Is this just a case of leaving a browser tab open and coming back to the tab later, taking great pains to make sure the question needs to be re-opened or not, or is it something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reviewer in these cases seems to have left the tab open and then come back to review it *after* the item was already reviewed to completion. (We record "review duration" on our end, and he spent ~20 minutes on each of these reviews.) This may have been done to exceed the daily review limit.

In general, we give everyone credit for a review, even if the item has already been completed.  To prevent behavior like this, though, we'll add new logic to *not* count reviews that took over <strike>two</strike> [**edit**:] 15 minutes if the review item has already been completed.

Comment: Two minutes seems a bit short--I would be surprised if I hadn't spent longer than that actually reviewing something. Reopen reviews on questions closed as dupes when the topic is one I'm less familiar with are the slowest.

Comment: We can up the time window a bit, but bear in mind that the 2 minutes only affects you when the review *becomes completed by other reviewers* while you're still reviewing it. For example, you get an item to review, and if in the five minutes it takes you to review it, other people complete the review, then you won't get any credit for your review.